# Text Callout not working in acrobat javascript

Tags: javascript, adobe, acrobat

I'm trying to insert Text callout, however its not showing up. It only showing the annotation box without arrow pointer. Please refer the code mentioned below:

```
var annot = this.addAnnot({
        page: 0,
        type: "FreeText",
        intent: "FreeTextCallout",
        rect: [10, 10, 10, 10],
        richContents: spans
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the "callout" property. The callout property is an array of six numbers specifying a callout line attached to the free text annotation. The six numbers [ x1 y1 x2 y2 x3 y3 ] represent the starting, knee point, and ending coordinates of the line in default user space. See the graphic.

[image]